# How to make enter key start new string on new line in processing?

Tags: processing

I've been working on coding a typography program in processing, and I can't seem to get the enter key to work the way I'd like. Here is my code:

```java
String vtl = "";
float cursor;
int vtly = 20;

void setup(){
  size(800, 200);
  textSize(15);
  stroke(0);
  fill(0);
}
void draw(){
  background(250);
  cursor = textWidth(vtl);
  line(cursor, vtly - 15, cursor, vtly);
  text(vtl, 0, vtly);
}
void keyPressed(){
    if(textWidth(vtl + key) == width){
      vtly = vtly + 25;
    }
    if(key == BACKSPACE){
      if(vtl.length() > 0){
        vtl = vtl.substring(0, vtl.length() - 1);
      }
    }else if(textWidth(vtl + key) < width){
       vtl = vtl + key;
    }

    if(key == ENTER){
      vtly = vtly + 15;
      vtl = "\n";
    }
}
```

Whenever the enter key is pressed, the whole first line is deleted. How can  I fix this?

Comment: You assign vtl value of "\n" at the end. How about assining it with vtl = vtl + "\n"; ?

Comment: That doesn't work. It sends the first line down and starts typing about 3 lines down from that.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this line:

```
vtl = "\n";
```

Here you're setting `vtl` to `"\n"`, which throws away the old value of `vtl`. If you want to append a newline to the end of the `String`, you have to add it to the existing value:

```
vtl = vtl + "\n";
```

Which can be shortened to:

```
vtl += "\n";
```

After that you've got other problems with the vertical placement of text, but that's a separate question.

Comment: Well if you're going to tell me that, you might as well tell me how to fix it.

Comment: @I_Am_The_Ion_Man Please keep in mind that we're all volunteering to answer questions for free, in our spare time. I didn't really start thinking about the vertical placement, because you didn't mention it in your question. I was giving you the chance to figure it out on your own. But if you're going to be rude, I'd just as soon spend my time answering other questions anyway. Have a good one.